# How do I programmatically turn on/off Mute Groups on my Behringer X32?

Tags: sockets, udp, libraries, osc

I've got a Behringer X32 rack, which uses an extension of the OSC (Open Sound Control) protocol. This particular rack communicates via UDP packets on port 10023. A fellow named Patrick Maillot actually has some [pretty extensive albeit unofficial documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/patrickmaillot/x32) of the protocol, including multiple executables you can download to interact with the system (outside of the official Behringer apps).

What I would like to do is pretty simple, though I'm having a hard time getting up to speed with this. I want to be able to mute and subsequently un-mute Mute Group 1 on my device. The mute group is already set up; all I want to do is utilize the protocol to either activate or deactivate it.

I can successfully connect to the rack using the X32_Command.exe program. But wading through the documentation, here's what I came up with as my best guess for which commands I should be sending:

> /config/mute/1/ON
>
> /config/mute/1/OFF

However, I don't think I have the syntax right (or maybe I've just got the wrong set of commands altogether), because those don't seem to do anything. In the X32_Command.exe console application I appear to receive the following responses when issuing those commands, respectively:

> ->X,   20 B: /config/mute/1/ON~~~
>
> ->X,   20 B: /config/mute/1/OFF~~

However, nothing actually happens on the rack. The mute group isn't affected at all when I issue these commands. How do I get this working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: strictly speaking, it seems like you haven't got as far as actually trying to write any code, so this would be off topic here [since it appears to be an OSC protocol question, not a coding one].

Comment: If there's one thing I've learned about Stack Overflow, it's that you can always count on at least one commenter to be a troll and immediately try to distract from the question with unhelpful pedantry!

Comment: Not trolling, I'm big into MIDI gear etc and I'm interested in this (heck, I even up-voted the question until I realised it wasn't programming related).  However this question seems more appropriate for the author of `X32_Command.exe` or some other OSC protocol forum at this point.  SO is mostly for when you try to write your own code to talk to it and can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw this (better late than never). The correct syntax for X32_Commmand.exe would be (as stated in the documentation):

> /config/mute/1 ,i 0
>
> /config/mute/1 ,i 1